# Bootstrap slider not working

Tags: customization, theme-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html bootstrap slider which works fine with captions and everything.I would like to integrate it into my Wp theme (my forst one, so total newbie).I found a code, which seems to helo, but it only shows the three pictures and nothing slides...if I hard code the slider, it works.I understand I can just leave it hard coded, but then it's not really WP ;) THANKS.
Here is the code:
functions.php - now complete file.

```
function load_stylesheets()
{

wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), 1,'all');

wp_enqueue_style('style');

wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), 1,'all');

wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

wp_register_style('fixedcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fixed.css', array(), 1,'all');

wp_enqueue_style('fixedcss');

wp_register_style('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.css', array(), 1,'all');

wp_enqueue_style('custom');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');


//load scripts

function load_javascript()
{

wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', 'jquery', 1, true);
wp_enqueue_script('custom');

wp_register_script('bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'), 1 , true);
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript');


// normal menue theme support
add_theme_support('menus');

// register menus, =>__ is improtant for tansaltions!
register_nav_menus
(

array('top-menu' =>__('Top Menu', 'theme')
)

);

//woocommerce theme suport

function customtheme_add_woocommerce_support()
 {
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'customtheme_add_woocommerce_support' );


//Images Slider

    function themename_slider_home_images_setup($wp_customize)
    {
        $wp_customize->add_section('home-slider-images', array(
            'title' => 'Home Slider',
            ));
    
            $wp_customize->add_setting('home-slider-first-image');
        $wp_customize->add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'home-slider-first-image',
                array(
                    'label'      => __( 'First Image', 'theme_name' ),
                    'section'    => 'home-slider-images',
                    'settings'   => 'home-slider-first-image'
                )
            )
            );
    
            $wp_customize->add_setting('home-slider-second-image');
        $wp_customize->add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'home-slider-second-image',
                array(
                    'label'      => __( 'Second Image', 'theme_name' ),
                    'section'    => 'home-slider-images',
                    'settings'   => 'home-slider-second-image'
                )
            )
            );
    
            $wp_customize->add_setting('home-slider-third-image');
        $wp_customize->add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'home-slider-third-image',
                array(
                    'label'      => __( 'Third Image', 'theme_name' ),
                    'section'    => 'home-slider-images',
                    'settings'   => 'home-slider-third-image'
                )
            )
        );
    }
    add_action('customize_register', 'themename_slider_home_images_setup');`
```

front-page.php:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('home-slider-first-image');?>" alt="caption3!" >
   
  </div>

  <div class="item header-image"
    <img  src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('home-slider-second-image');?>" alt="caption2" >
  </div>

  <div class="item header-image">
    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('home-slider-third-image');?>" alt="I am a caption" 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Anna. Do you get any output in the browser inspector in the sections where you are echoing out your functions? Is it empty or wrong?

Comment: t2pe, sorry am really just learning, not sure what you mean?

Comment: Ok, so in your browser you can right click on the page and select inspect. This will show you the code that your site is actually generating so you can compare it to what you're expecting. If you inspect the Carousel code itself, look within the item as thats where your function is creating an output. Just make sure it looks correct in there - that you're not for instance seeing an <img> within an <img>. Compare it to your hard-coded version.

Comment: ;O) thanks!They are the same, just the class is called differntly.

Comment: Ok, thats good as it proves your customizations are working correctly. Looking at your carousel code in front-page.php, it doesn't quite follow the bootstrap 4 conventions? Just check the documentation here as it might be that your html structure is the problem. The item classes in particular are different. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your question correctly with `wp_enqueue_script` but it doesn't appear in your code so you are probably missing the jQuery library and bootstrap by the looks of it.

Try adding the following:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_add_jquery');

function wp_add_jquery () {
    wp_register_script( 'my_jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
    // Add your other scripts here (bootstrap, etc.)

}
```

Comment: See edited code pls ;) tried yours did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Check with bootstrap & Jquery dependency file enqueue.

You need to load your bootstrap style & Jquery by the action wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script.

**Example:** In functions.php

```
    function my_scripts() {

   wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap4', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot1','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot3','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Also in your custom js you need to put this `$('.carousel').carousel();`

Comment: Suresh, thank you, I think I am not getting it... put the code into my custom.js file, but bothing happens ;)

Comment: Hello Anna, for carousel init you need to put this code $('.carousel').carousel(); in your js file

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

to my funcitons.php and now it works, I suppose there must have been a conflict with my enqueued jquery.